# How to gather information/debug when we have only the core file

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

I have came across a situation where we have only the core file (no executable).
How can i use the core file with gdb or any other tool to gather as much information as possible.

```
gdb core
GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.1-8.9.1)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-suse-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
"/home/core": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have came across a situation where we have only the core file (no executable).

Surely you have the executable *somewhere*? Get a copy of it if you can.

> How can i use the core file with gdb or any other tool to gather as much information as possible.

Unless you configured the host to dump file-backed shared mappings (see `coredump_filter`[documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)), you simply can't extract much meaningful info from the core.

> `gdb core`

Don't do that. Do this instead: `gdb -c core`. Then `where`, and `info registers` and possibly `print $_siginfo` may provide something, but it will not be much.